# Access Query CurrentDb.OpenRecordset

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I try to create a query in MS Access (VBA) where I can select only the current dataset (by ID) shown in the query form. Somehow my query does not work .. do you have a suggestion for me?

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM query1 WHERE ID = [Forms]![query1]![ID]"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant include your variables in your string. Try it like this instead.

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM query1 WHERE ID =" & [Forms]![query1]![ID]
```

Comment: thank you for your fast help! that was the solution.

Comment: You are welcome @jMajik - Please remember to accept the answer (after 10 minutes) so that it does not remain open.